# Mapping $\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb F_3$ in the canonical way.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm running through a proof of a question that omits some details and want to make sure my interpretation is correct

> Let $R=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$. I am asked to show that $R[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals.

In the previous part of the question we proved that $\Bbb F{_3}[x] \cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals.

The question recommends using that there is a surjective  ring homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow \Bbb F{_3}[x]$ mapping  $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb F{_3}$ in the canonical way. I believe so we can use its surjectivity to induce an injective map from $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb F{_3}[x])  \rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (the sets of prime ideals), which is a result from a previous question that would complete the proof.

Is this to say: we consider $\phi$ to be the canonical projection map  from $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \rightarrow (\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z)/(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ (where $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ (?))

If so, how to show $(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z)/(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ and if not, what am i misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the last question: consider the map $\mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ where $x\mapsto 2x$ then use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not an ideal of $6\mathbb Z$. Do you mean $2\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$? Then apply one of the isomorphism theorems. The map suggested in the first comment will not work because it is not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\mathbb{Z_6}=\mathbb{Z_3} \rtimes \mathbb{Z_2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310250/why-is-mathbbz-6-mathbbz-3-rtimes-mathbbz-2)

Comment: The canonical map $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is just reduction mod $3$. The kernel is $3 \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \{0, 3\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way would be to mod out by the ideal $(3)$.  The quotient is $\Bbb F_3$.